# "Expires_at" column: amount of hours or the final value?

Tags: database, schema

Say, I have an entity which has a column "inserted_at". Now I want to add a column "expires_at". It can be in hours, days or months.

There're 2 approaches to this:

1) add 2 columns: valid_within_value:int and valid_within_unit_id. Or even a single column: valid_within_value_in_hours:int

2) or add expires_at: datetime

What are the cons and procs of each of these? Which one is more common and recommended and when?

Comment: see [What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you're trying to accomplish with expiration.

Is keeping track of a period of validity interesting to your app over a long period of time? E.g. you could have many differing expiration durations, and you need to compare and contrast requests based on how long a 'time to live' (ttl) they were given. If so, that argues for keeping around an actual duration value.

However, if you need to actually select items for expiration, strongly recommend you compute and keep an absolute `expires_at` value. Otherwise, you will be constantly recomputing these values to determine "Did it happen yet? Can we expire it?" Which devolves quickly into a "No. Okay. *twiddles a while* Recomptes values. How about now? No? Okay. ..." loop.

If you need to both evaluate/reason about differing expirations and actual expire, keep both figures around. However, that would be a rare case. Usually, expiring is the goal and there's no (or not much) variation in expiration duration, and no (or only infrequent) interest in reasoning about it. In which case, just the computed endpoint nicely suffices.

Answer (score 3):

A good rule of thumb: If you are in doubt, use the simplest possible solution. In this case having a single `expires_at` which is an unambiguous DateTime value is clearly simplest.

Introducing units or values relative to other values only adds complexity. Unless you have some requirement which you don't mention, don't add complexity you don't need.